# pandas dataframe groupby and join

Tags: python, pandas, join, group-by

Let's suppose to have this:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                          'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                           'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                   'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
```

So the dataframe appears like below:

```
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one -1.085631  1.265936
1  bar    one  0.997345 -0.866740
2  foo    two  0.282978 -0.678886
3  bar  three -1.506295 -0.094709
4  foo    two -0.578600  1.491390
5  bar    two  1.651437 -0.638902
6  foo    one -2.426679 -0.443982
7  foo  three -0.428913 -0.434351
```

I want to group the `df` by `B`, calculate the sum of `C` column multiplied by the sum of `D` column for each group and finally joining this grouped-by result with the original `df`.
In Python:

```
grouped = df.groupby('B').apply(lambda group: sum(group['C'])*sum(group['D'])).reset_index()
grouped.columns = ['B', 'new_value']
df.join(grouped.set_index('B'), on='B')
```

There exists a more *pythonic* and efficient way to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
In [25]: df.groupby('B')['C','D'].transform('sum').prod(1)
Out[25]:
0    0.112635
1    0.112635
2    0.235371
3    1.023841
4    0.235371
5    0.235371
6    0.112635
7    1.023841
dtype: float64
```

Solution 2:

```
In [18]: grp = df.groupby('B')

In [19]: grp['C'].transform('sum') * grp['D'].transform('sum')
Out[19]:
0    0.112635
1    0.112635
2    0.235371
3    1.023841
4    0.235371
5    0.235371
6    0.112635
7    1.023841
dtype: float64
```

Demo:

```
In [20]: df
Out[20]:
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one -1.085631  1.265936
1  bar    one  0.997345 -0.866740
2  foo    two  0.282978 -0.678886
3  bar  three -1.506295 -0.094709
4  foo    two -0.578600  1.491390
5  bar    two  1.651437 -0.638902
6  foo    one -2.426679 -0.443982
7  foo  three -0.428913 -0.434351

In [21]: grp = df.groupby('B')

In [22]: df['new'] = grp['C'].transform('sum') * grp['D'].transform('sum')

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
     A      B         C         D       new
0  foo    one -1.085631  1.265936  0.112635
1  bar    one  0.997345 -0.866740  0.112635
2  foo    two  0.282978 -0.678886  0.235371
3  bar  three -1.506295 -0.094709  1.023841
4  foo    two -0.578600  1.491390  0.235371
5  bar    two  1.651437 -0.638902  0.235371
6  foo    one -2.426679 -0.443982  0.112635
7  foo  three -0.428913 -0.434351  1.023841


In [26]: df['new2'] = df.groupby('B')['C','D'].transform('sum').prod(1)

In [27]: df
Out[27]:
     A      B         C         D       new      new2
0  foo    one -1.085631  1.265936  0.112635  0.112635
1  bar    one  0.997345 -0.866740  0.112635  0.112635
2  foo    two  0.282978 -0.678886  0.235371  0.235371
3  bar  three -1.506295 -0.094709  1.023841  1.023841
4  foo    two -0.578600  1.491390  0.235371  0.235371
5  bar    two  1.651437 -0.638902  0.235371  0.235371
6  foo    one -2.426679 -0.443982  0.112635  0.112635
7  foo  three -0.428913 -0.434351  1.023841  1.023841
```

Check:

```
In [28]: df.new.eq(df.new2).all()
Out[28]: True
```

Comment: what if i need two new column: the one already mentioned and another one 'second_new' equal to the sum of D column. I don't like write two different transform lines...

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

You can take the sum in the `groupby` over just columns `['C', 'D']` then perform `prod` across `axis=1` (row rise, across columns).  This will be a reduced dataframe with an index equal to the unique values in column `B`.  You can use `join` with `on='B'` to link back up.  Make sure you `rename` the `pd.Series` with the name you'd like the column to be.

```
df.join(df.groupby('B')['C', 'D'].sum().prod(1).rename('newCol'), on='B')
```

### Solution 2

Same idea as in solution 1 except we use `map` + `assign` to combine with existing dataframe `df`

```
df.assign(newCol=df.B.map(df.groupby('B')['C', 'D'].sum().prod(1)))
```

---

Both yield

```
     A      B         C         D    newCol
0  foo    one -1.085631  1.265936  0.112635
1  bar    one  0.997345 -0.866740  0.112635
2  foo    two  0.282978 -0.678886  0.235371
3  bar  three -1.506295 -0.094709  1.023841
4  foo    two -0.578600  1.491390  0.235371
5  bar    two  1.651437 -0.638902  0.235371
6  foo    one -2.426679 -0.443982  0.112635
7  foo  three -0.428913 -0.434351  1.023841
```