# Python: how to groupby and count without aggregating the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My dataframe looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to group by columns ['name', 'grade'], and perform count(), the result looks like this:

**df.groupby(['name', 'grade'], as_index=False).count()**

[image]

But what I want should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us little more source code?

Comment: year = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011], 
name = ['kelly', 'kelly', kelly', 'peter', 'peter], 
grade = ['A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B'], 
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'year': year, 'name': name, 'grade': grade})

Answer (score 2):

try using `transform`:

```
dict = {"year": [2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011],
   "name": ["kelly", "kelly", "kelly", "peter", "peter"],
   "grade": ["A", "A", "C", "B", "B"] }

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df)

grp = df.groupby(['name', 'grade'], as_index=False)
print(grp.count())

df['count'] = grp['year'].transform('count')
print(df)
```

PS: credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41925722/1681985